# Client-Server - How do i filter only dedicated software sending data?

Tags: c++, encryption, client-server

I am writing a server and client code where i want to identify on server side official client software sending data.

The protocol is text based, so anyone can write it's own client - and i want to keep it, but want to group the devices by "Official" / "Non Official" based on the 'fingerprint' of my official client application.

Question:

How can i filter out my clients from other clones sending?

I am thinking to send encrypted message from my client to SERVER using the same key, so once decoded if it's valid, then i know its my app code sending - but before i go this way, any other better ideas ?

Comment: This seems a technical (poor) answer to an issue best handled by contracts approved by professional lawyer

Comment: And you should at least explain a lot more your protocol. Why don't you use HTTP or WebSockets?

Comment: Its pretty much impossible to do it. Your time is better spent setting limits on what can and cannot be done and deciding whether the client is well behaved or not based on some heuristics such as the rate of actions (and what kind) they're trying to do if its an actual concern. It is trivial to extract a fingerprint from legit application and put it into custom one and you'd actually be making the abuser's job only easier by doing that.

Comment: I usually implement an algorithm that creates a key basing on current datetime and other varying data from the server, the clients on connection send the key so the server can recognize them. The difficulty to reverse engineering depends on how complicated the algorithm is and which data involves

Comment: I have developed a framework that does exactly what you are describing. It's a very difficult task. 1) you have to receive connection requests as fast as they come or you can get denial-of-service attacked, 2) you need to solve connector authentication either by a priori methods like I did, or by using Diffie-Helman protocol. This is to protect your listening end point, 3) don't use Ipv4 even though Ipv6 inter-ISP reachability doesn't exist yet. It will by the time you are done with your code. Good luck